# For loop won't loop past first variable in sequence when used in function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe including lab results for individual subjects. Some of the subjects have duplicate records, only that the duplicates have certain data points missing in one record, but not in the other.

I'm trying to write a function that will "fill in" the NA data points in one line from any duplicate that may exist for that subject. Here's what I tried:

```
# example data with duplicate IDs, some with missing values

ir<-head(iris)
ir$unique_flower_ID<-1:6
ir<-rbind(ir, ir[c(1,3,5),])
ir[7:9, c(1,3)]<-NA
ir[c(1,3,5), c(2,4)]<-NA
ir<-ir[order(ir$unique_flower_ID),]

# function to run on a given dataframe (df) to 
# replace missing values in certain variables (vars) from duplicates
# as identified by a unique ID
replaceNAs_dupl <- function(df, ID, vars) {
  #identify duplicate IDs and subset the dataframe
  df_dupl<-data.frame(table(df[, ID]))
  df_dupl<-df[df[, ID] %in% df_dupl$Var1[which(df_dupl$Freq > 1)],]

  # loop through specified columns
  for(i in vars) {
    #create a mini-dataframe of ID and value for each column
    df_dupl_uni<-unique(df_dupl[which(!is.na(df_dupl[,i])), c(ID, i)])
    # replace missing data with data from duplicate record
    df[which(df[, ID] %in% df_dupl_uni[, ID]), i] <- df_dupl_uni[match(df[which(df[, ID] %in% df_dupl_uni[, ID]), ID], df_dupl_uni[, ID]), i]

    return(df)
    }      
}

# define the columns to run the function on by name
col_names<-colnames(ir[,1:4])

# pass ir to the function
ir2<-replaceNAs_dupl(ir, "unique_flower_ID", col_names)
```

The output works, but only for the first column; the loop simply won't loop.

1. Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?
2. Is there a better way entirely to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: Your `return` statement needs to be outside the for loop. It is exiting at the end of the first loop run right now.

Comment: @DanTan, fyi I disagree with your edits to the question. *"I'm new"* is not always that helpful to the question, but it can change the shape of answers. For instance, a terse answer might be enough for a moderately-seasoned programmer, but newer programmers might need more explanation. I agree that sometimes it can seem like noise (and so reducing repeated or over-the-top "I'm a noob" might be appropriate), but some mention is still useful. Ref: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97620/should-we-remove-im-a-newbie-so-please-help-me-lines

Comment: @r2evans, got it, thanks for taking the time to explain and link that meta discussion. I was going off of the "Remove all Noise" guidelines [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit). Meta irony alert: I'm fairly new to editing posts on SO, so taking the time to give me some guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: I've done similar edits, and my position on this an related topics has "evolved" based on meta and pedagogic biases. Keep at it, please, the community benefits from attentive users.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Wonder if I should change the question to something like "function for filling NAs from duplicates in multiple columns" or something, to make the main content of the answers more findable for others. Any suggestions from the more experienced users?

Comment: I think your question title is appropriate as-is: your original problem (initially identified/fixed by jdobres' comment) was that you were `return`ing too early. The rest of my answer was extra-credit, providing an alternative solution that I thought was perhaps more efficient. If you were to change the title to *"filling NAs"*, then you'd need to change the body of the question, which then changes the intent. It's happened before on SO, but that's enough of a departure from the original issue that it is typically frowned upon (to shift that much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jdobres said, your initial problem is that you are `return`ing within the loop, before it can iterate further.

I offer as an alternate implementation, the following code:

```r
library(dplyr)
ir %>%
  group_by(unique_flower_ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), ~ if_else(is.na(.), na.omit(.)[1], .)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 6
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species unique_flower_ID
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>              <int>
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa                 1
# 2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa                 1
# 3          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa                 2
# 4          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa                 3
# 5          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa                 3
# 6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa                 4
# 7          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa                 5
# 8          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa                 5
# 9          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa                 6
```

---

How it works:

1. grouping by the ID field means that the code below will be executed once for each unique id; meaning the first time the `mutate_at` function is called, it will see only

   ```
      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species unique_flower_ID
   1           5.1          NA          1.4          NA  setosa                1
   11           NA         3.5           NA         0.2  setosa                1
   ```
2. `mutate_at` does the same function on one or more columns, in this case all columns between (and including) `Sepal.Length` and `Petal.Width`;
3. the function called is using `rlang`'s "tilde notation", in which the dot `.` will be replaced with the vector of data within each column, effectively doing each of

   ```r
   if_else(is.na(Sepal.Length), na.omit(Sepal.Length)[1], Sepal.Length)
   if_else(is.na(Sepal.Width), na.omit(Sepal.Width)[1], Sepal.Width)
   if_else(is.na(Petal.Length), na.omit(Petal.Length)[1], Petal.Length)
   if_else(is.na(Petal.Width), na.omit(Petal.Width)[1], Petal.Width)
   ```

   (it could just as easily have been `mutate_at(..., function(a) if_else(is.na(a), na.omit(a)[1], a))`, but I like the more compact `~` notation)
4. within that function, for each value in the vector, if it is non-`NA` then it is used without change; if it is `NA`, then it replaces the `NA` with the first non-`NA` value in the frame ("first" means first in the frame, so if there are multiple distinct values, you must control which gets priority by the order of your rows);
5. this safeguards against having no available data in a column by using `na.omit(.)[1]`: if `na.omit(.)` returns *nothing* (vector of length 0, as in `na.omit(NA)`), then the `[1]` forces it to return *something*, which in our case is (another) `NA`, so we retain a full vector. For example:

   ```r
   ir$Sepal.Length[1:2] <- NA
   ir %>%
     group_by(unique_flower_ID) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width), ~ if_else(is.na(.), na.omit(.)[1], .)) %>%
     ungroup()
   # # A tibble: 9 x 6
   #   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species unique_flower_ID
   #          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>              <int>
   # 1         NA           3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa                 1
   # 2         NA           3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa                 1
   # 3          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa                 2
   # 4          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa                 3
   # 5          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa                 3
   # 6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa                 4
   # 7          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa                 5
   # 8          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa                 5
   # 9          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa                 6
   ```

(PS: since you're new to R, I should clarify: the use of `rlang`'s tilde notation is unique to the `tidyverse` packages; it is not necessarily available in other packages/functions unless explicitly provided as such. For those, one should use the more generic anonymous function (e.g., `function(a) { ... }`) or a named function.)

Comment: The `na.omit(.)[1]` seems clunky. Maybe use `tidyr::fill` and replace the whole `if_else` with `~fill(fill(., direction = "up"))`?

Comment: Ugh, I always forget that `fill` acts on data frames, not vectors. You could replace the `mutate` with two separate `fill`s, or use nested `zoo::na.locf()` as in my first comment, with `fromLast = TRUE` in one of them. Not super-clean, but still perhaps clearer than `na.omit(.)[1]`

Comment: I don't disagree that a double-`fill` (or double-`zoo::na.locf`) would also work, but what's the gain over `na.omit(.)[1]`? How is it less clear? I'm good either way, I think all three options are viable improvements over the previous `for` loop.

Comment: I say "less clear" because I'm pretty good at R, I read your code before reading the question, and I had no idea what  that `[1]` was doing there until I read your bullets 4 and 5. It's unusual to use `na.omit` to fill in missing values, so it requires explanation even to people familiar with `na.omit`. Using `fill` or `na.locf` for their intended purpose doesn't require extra explanation.

Comment: *"pretty good at R"*, yeah, foregone conclusion and understatement, Gregor :-). Three things motivated my use of `na.omit`: (1) base functions over more external packages (though I admit that if `dplyr` is installed, so likely is `tidyr::fill`); (2) single pass over the vectors instead of two without any significant increase in elegant/clarity; (3) I actually thought `na.omit(.)[1]` was fairly direct/clear in saying "the first non-NA", it seems my perceptions/assumptions are a little skewed (no harm, no offense). My use of `dplyr` was pedagogic, so perhaps I should have included `tidyr`, too.

Comment: Yeah, I only mentioned `fill` since you were already using `dplyr`. `zoo::na.locf` would have been my go-to otherwise, may not in base but it's the classic tool for the job. (2) is an excellent point. It only *really* matters if data is large enough to matter, but of course it's good to build & encourage good habits even when the bad habits do little harm. To (3), I'm just one guy, y'know? Maybe others would have easily understood. But after reading your 5th bullet I had to go try it out before I really believed you. I'm wasn't sure `integer(0)[1]` would return `NA` and not an error.

Comment: Nice answer---especially that detailed explanation, regardless of if we end up on different sides of the split hair of which method is clearer.

Comment: That means a lot coming from you, Gregor. I was just telling MrFlick at rstudio::conf last month that when I'm formulating a question on SO, I often hear "SO/R regulars" (you, MrFlick, akrun, to name a few) asking me to simplify this, expand that, blah blah ... and when doing so I answer my own question and click "cancel". I bet you didn't know you were talking to me as much as I heard :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's really lovely to hear. I've certainly typed up, solved, and *not* submitted more questions than I've actually asked on SO. I didn't plan enough in advance this year, but I'm definitely hoping to make the next rstudio::conf.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, because it not only points out my error in the original code, but offers a better solution, and, most importantly, explains it well enough that I might just have a chance to expand my R vocabulary by actively adapting these function calls, which are new to me. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple (but somewhat naive) solution for merging records.

```
library(dplyr)
ir2 <- ir %>% 
  group_by(unique_flower_ID) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Limitations:

- This merges records, meaning there will no longer be duplicates, which may not be desirable.
- If there are ever two duplicate records that don't match, it takes the average value. `mean` could be replaced with another summary function, but it might be preferable to throw some sort of error if you ever had two records with the same ID but different values in a given column.
- If all records with a given ID have NA's in a column, it returns `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks, this is not exactly what I was looking for, but 1. it solves a seperate problem I still need to address and 2. I feel like I actually understand the syntax. Upvoted.